# jQuery .pop() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this function running, anyway I caught a problem like this
**"Uncaught TypeError: this.chart_data.pop is not a function"**

Here is my code

```
 $(data).each(function(){
    console.log(this.chart_data);
    console.log(this.chart_data.pop());
    var end = (this.chart_data).pop();

    ret.push({
        name: this.name,
        y: end['y'],
        link: this.link,
        color: chart_colours[i]
    });

    i++;

});
```

Thank you for your concern and help.

Comment: You iterate over `data`, yet are trying to use `this.chart_data`. If you use `.each`, you don't need to keep popping the values, you can use the current value passed into the function. This also means you don't need to use your `i` variable (which hasn't been initialised anyway).

Comment: a [mcve] would be great.

Answer (score 1):

this line will always give you an error:

```
console.log(this.chart_data.pop());
```

I am not sure why you displaying the pop method. Still, you need to replace the above line with the following:

```
 console.log($(this.chart_data).pop());
```

and use pop method like this while assigning:

```
 var end = $(this.chart_data).pop();
```